# How to left pad an integer with 0's (zeros)?

Tags: c, printf

I want the program to return 4 digits even if the number is less than 4 digits long.
for example:
1 -> 0001
I tried:

```
printf("%4d",number);
```

but it only returns three spaces then the number one, it doesn't add the 0s before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, white spaces are used for padding, you should add `0` to the format specifier to make the padding character `0`s.

```
printf("%04d",number);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Yu Hao's answer, you can also specify the digit count dynamically:

```
printf("%0*d", digit_count, number);
```